# Should I prefer ThreadLocalRandom or SecureRandom?

Tags: java, security, random

I know that `Random` class generates insecure random sequences and I should prefer using `SecureRandom` when dealing with security. But what about `ThreadLocalRandom`? Is it more or less secure?

```
// generate a five-digit numeric confirmation code
Long code = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 99999);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As described in [its javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html), `ThreadLocalRandom` is similar to `Random` (i.e. not secure) but with better performance in case of concurrent access.

> Instances of `ThreadLocalRandom` are not cryptographically secure. Consider instead using `SecureRandom` in security-sensitive applications.

Answer (score 8):

`ThreadLocalRandom` is something like `ThreadLocal<Random>` which creates `Random` instance per thread. This has nothing to do with safety in cryptography context.

So the question is *"what is the difference between `Random` and `SecureRandom`"* implementations.

`SecureRandom` differs in that, it **passed tests that are required for safety in cryptography**. Exactly it passed tests specified by *FIPS 140-2* (standard for generators used in cryptography). For more details see [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) javadoc.