# SecureRandom is unreasonably slow or freezes the system

Tags: java, jenkins, random, freeze, secure-random

A java application does something like this:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
   random.nextInt(19);
}
```

At random.nextInt() the java freezes for several minutes, seems it hangs indefinitely.
The weird part is that the behaviour is present only when I ran it through Jenkins, and I wasn’t able to reproduce the problem locally.
Also in production the code works fine.
The jenkins agent is an Ubuntu, however If I change it to a macOS agent, it works fine.
The production runs on openSUSE.
What's the magic here?

Comment: You probably want to add your OS type/version to make this really helpful.

Comment: Related [jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-20108?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&showAll=true)

Answer (score 8):

## Solution 1 (changing the code)

Use `ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt()` instead.

**edit**:  ThreadLocalRandom is not "secure".
Use this only if your case is not security-sensitive.
SecureRandom is FIPS 140-2 compliant, see:

- [Should I prefer ThreadLocalRandom or SecureRandom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44502167/should-i-prefer-threadlocalrandom-or-securerandom/44502441)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2

## Solution 2 (without release, still secure)

Add a JVM argument to the runner:
`-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom`

### Why is that?

So that was a little bit tricky.
`SecureRandom` relies on the OS random generator, which is `/dev/random` by default.
`/dev/random` relies on environment noise, such as mouse input.
If there is not enough environment noise, `/dev/random` is blocked by design. (actually depends on linux distro)
**Boom!** Locally you have system noise all the time, but on a jenkins agent maybe not.

#### Source

- [SecureRandom can hang, Sándor Németh](https://sandor.tech/java/2017/08/02/securerandom-can-hang.html) - many thanks!
- [Weblogic is slow to start (11mins) under VM (VirtualBox and VMware)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563135/weblogic-is-slow-to-start-11mins-under-vm-virtualbox-and-vmware)
- [wikipedia /dev/random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random)

Comment: Solution 1 isn't a replacement as it uses a regular `Random` and not a `SecureRandom`.

Comment: You are right, updated